# Should you nest Stack Navigators in React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Should you keep navigators flat? Or nest where it makes sense from a logical/UI point of view.

e.g.

```
App1: {
    Login,
    Register,
    Profile,
    Chats,
    Friends
}
```

versus

```
App2: {
    LoginStack: {
        Login,
        Register
    },
    MainStack: {
        Profile,
        Chats,
        Friends
    }
}
```

In `App1` there is just a single stack for the app. You could then maneuver the screens depending on sign in, etc. While in `App2` there are nested stack navigators, one for signed in and one for not.

Would the answer if Redux is being used?

Answer (score 0):

As of `react-navigation` `v5`, we can nest the following together as multi-level.

```
@react-navigation/drawer
@react-navigation/native
@react-navigation/stack
```

But multiple level nesting of Stack navigation alone is failing.

For `v4`, you can refer to [this blog](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/complex-navigation-example-with-react-navigation).